# How to properly implement derived classes with their own functions in a Factory Pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, virtual-functions, factory-pattern

I face a problem with derived classes having their own functions when using Factory Pattern. Please share how you design OOP in this case.

Assume I have a general class `B`, and many derived classes, named `D1, D2, D3`, etc. Each of these classes has its own function, named `F1, F2, F3`, etc. respectively. Using Factory Pattern, we will have a program like this:

```cpp
class FactoryPattern {
    static B* create(string type) {
        if (type == "D1")
            return new D1();
        if (type == "D2")
            return new D2();
        ...
    }
};
```

However, `B` must have its virtual functions for all of the `F`, and for each of the derived classes, I will print (or throw an error or anything else) to prevent the user from using the functions.

With the below implementation, the program will **scale tremendously**, as when we need to implement a new function, for example, function `F3` for class `D3`, we need to update the program for both `D1` and `D2`.

```cpp
class B {
protected:
    virtual void F1() = 0;
    virtual void F2() = 0;
};

class D1: public B {
public:
    void F1() {
        cout << "F1 from D1\n";
    }

    void F2() {
        cout << "This function is not implemented\n";
    }
};

class D2: public B {
public:
    void F1() {
        cout << "This function is not implemented\n";
    }

    void F2() {
        cout << "F2 from D2\n";
    }
};
```

I thought about using a general function for class `B`, and just overriding if needed in the derived class, however, when combining with Factory Pattern, the returned pointer calls directly to `B::F1` and `B::F2`, which are not implemented.

```cpp
class B {
protected:
    void F1() {
        cout << "This function is not implemented\n";
    }
    void F2() {
        cout << "This function is not implemented\n";
    }
};

class D1: public B {
public:
    void F1() {
        cout << "F1 from D1\n";
    }
};

class D2: public B {
public:
    void F2() {
        cout << "F2 from D2\n";
    }
};
```

**Edit:** The function `F` can take different types of parameters, and the naming is also specific, so I can not use a general function like `foo`.

**Edit2:** For a more detailed problem, let `Inference` be the general class (`B`), and I have 2 derived classes, named `Classifier`, and `Detector`. For initialisation, all of them take `model_path`, however, `Detector` can take the list of output information (`bounding_box`, `label`, etc.) in addition, then the initialisation of them will take different types of parameters. There are many other special functions, this is just an example.

```cpp
class Inference {
public:
    virtual void Initilisation(string model_path) = 0;
    virtual void Initilisation(string model_path, vector<string> output_information) = 0;

};

class Detector: public Inference {
public:
    void Initilisation(string model_path) {
        cout << "Not implemented\n";
    }

    void Initilisation(string model_path, vector<string> output_information) {
        // do some initialisation
        // for example, output_information can be {"label", "conf", ...}
    }
};

class Classifier: public Inference {
public:
    void Initilisation(string model_path) {
        // do some initialisation
    }

    void Initilisation(string model_path, vector<string> output_information) {
        cout << "Not implemented\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: When you implement the functions in the base class you still need to mark them as `virtual`. It doesn't sound like your derived classes are actually implementations of the base class which is why this pattern isn't working for you

Comment: This has nothing to do whatsoever with the factory pattern. *when combining with Factory Pattern, the returned pointer calls directly* You are mistaken somewhere, but we cannot tell you where exactly until you show a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. *when combining with Factory Pattern*. Sorry, I just want to refer to the usage of polymorphism, as a pointer of B point to class D.

Comment: inheritance isnt the solution to everything

Comment: So the code you show bears little resemblance to your real problem. How do you want us to help you? Please show a [mcve] where *the returned pointer calls directly to B::F1 and B::F2*.

Comment: A [mcve] is a program that I can *copy, paste, compile, run, and see the same problem you are seeing*, in that order, with no intermediate steps. Having said that, you are misusing inheritance. If your class needs to output "Not implemented", it is in the wrong place in the inheritance hierarchy. It looks like your two classes should not be siblings at all.

Comment: Having derived specific functions in the base class is not a good idea. Maybe the factory pattern is not what you need. It seems that you don't need/want polymorphism. Either you'll have to downcast to get your actual type, or you should simply remove the factory and create your classes directly.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a new function for each derived class kind of defeats to point of polymorphism. The usual way to go is to declare one `virtual` function in the base class, then to override it in the derivatives with their own functionality.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class D1: public B
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a D1\n";
    }
};

class D2: public B
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm a D2\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<B> pD1 = std::make_unique<D1>(D1());
  pD1->foo();

  std::unique_ptr<B> pD2 = std::make_unique<D2>(D2());
  pD2->foo();

  // pD1 and pD2 are of the same type, could be stored in the same vector etc.
}
```

Comment: The functions of derived classes take different types of parameters, and the function name is also specific, so `foo` might not work in my case.

Comment: I see your point "Declaring a new function for each derived class kind of defeats to point of polymorphism." Maybe I need to redesign my class diagram.

Comment: @dungdq: OK, so you need to be able to accept  different parameters. That compilicaties things, but maybe it can still be handled with this approach. 
Can you encapsulate the parameters somehow ? Put them in a struct or std::variant ?
Then again, do you really need polymorphism in the first place if you classes are not interchangeable to at least some degree ?

Comment: about the function name: just call the specific function from the inherited one `D1::foo(){fooD1();}`

Comment: I get the idea of wrapping, it is quite complicated. I think inheritance is a nice approach for my case, however, polymorphism is not suitable. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I studied about factory design pattern and it's uses. I have mentioned in this article. Please go through it. I hope it solves your doubt.

Check it out : https://deepakatariya.com/factory-design-pattern-can-help/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make an abstract baseclass first and make sure the factory returns unique pointers to that. unique_ptr because naked new/delete is not recommended in current C++. SO you will transfer ownership of the pointer to the caller of the factory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// When using a factor always start with an
// abstract baseclass (interface)

class my_interface_t
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

// then concrete classes, note the override keyword

class class_a_t :
    public my_interface_t
{
public:
    void do_something() override
    {
        std::cout << "class_a_t::do_something()\n";
    }
};

class class_b_t :
    public my_interface_t
{
public:
    void do_something() override
    {
        std::cout << "class_b_t::do_something()\n";
    }
};


class factory_t
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<my_interface_t> create(std::string_view name)
    {
        // do NOT use new/delete in current C++

        if (name == "A") return std::make_unique<class_a_t>();
        if (name == "B") return std::make_unique<class_b_t>();

        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid class name");
    }
};


int main()
{
    factory_t factory;
    auto a = factory.create("A");
    auto b = factory.create("B");

    a->do_something();
    b->do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The functions of derived classes take different types of parameters, and the function name is also specific, so `do_something` might not work in my case.

Comment: Ah you did not mention that, in that case inheritance will not work for you. But the whole idea of a factory should be that it can create interchangeable objects so you would need to find another way of passing the arguments.